# Finding eigenvalues for a specific 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I know the general process for finding eigenvalues, but I'm stuck on this particular matrix.  The matrix is:
$\begin{bmatrix}-13 & -8 &-4 \\
 12 & 7&4 \\
 24 &16 &7\end{bmatrix}$

When I try to compute the $\text{det}(A-\lambda I)$, I get an intractable algebra problem for the characteristic equation.  What's the secret here?

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  What did you get for the characteristic equation?  Did you try the rational zeros theorem or an online facility such as MathWay?

Comment: Use proper LaTeX please.

Comment: The secret is to do the algebra to obtain the char equation real SLOW.....because mistakes are made easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is it intractable? I get as the determinant $3 + 5 \lambda + \lambda^2 - \lambda^3$. There is a cubic formula for solving this equation:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html

it yields: $3 + 5 \lambda + \lambda^2 - \lambda^3 = -(\lambda - 3) (\lambda + 1)^2 = 0$, so $\lambda_1=-1$ and $\lambda_2=3$. The first eigenvalue obviously has algebraic multiplicity two.  So this matrix has a form
$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}$.

EDIT: It turns out that the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda = -1$ is two as well. So the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: Hahaha, thanks for the welcoming words :)) We are a pretty big family :D

Comment: I got it now.  My algebra was sloppy.  The hint to add row 2 to row 1 made for an easier factorization of the characteristic equation though.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: To calculate the determinant

$\begin{vmatrix} -13 - \lambda & -8 & -4\\
12 & 7 -\lambda & 4\\
24 & 16 & 7-\lambda \end{vmatrix}$

do the elementary row operation that replaces row 1 by row 1 plus row 2, and note that this does not change the determinant.